# When to create a new variable to store a value rather than calling function multiple times?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, jit

I once heard a difference between PHP and Java is in PHP the following is more efficient to store the return value of `foo()` than call it each time the conditional statement of the loop is evaluated:

```
$x = 1;
for($y = 0; $y < foo($x); $y++)
{
  //code goes here
}
```

vs

```
$x = 1;
$processed = foo($x);
for($y = 0; $y < $processed; $y++)
{
  //code goes here
}
```

In Java when is it worth it to create a variable who is only used to test conditional statements (and value is never changed). For example in a project I'm working on now has

```
int[] operator = new int[numberOfOperators(eqn)];
int[] numeric = new int[numberOfOperators(eqn) + 1];
for(int i = 0; i < operator.length; i++)
{
    //code goes here
}
```

Will the Java Optimizer or JIT compiler know what to do with this or should I create a new variable that holds the return value of `numberOfOperators()`?

Comment: Array lengths are a property, not a function.

Comment: @DaveNewton that's right. Why did you think otherwise? One thing I'd like to know is taking the value from a property as fast as taking the value from a variable?

Comment: This depends the implementation of the `numberOfOperators` method. The JIT can inline methods and eliminate redundant code. In some cases the JIT might do the optimisation for you.

Comment: @Celeritas I *didn't* think otherwise. You're comparing two completely different things: a method call, and a property access. At least that's what I thought at first; but you're asking about `numberOfOperators`, the return value of which could change between subsequent calls.

Comment: What happens when you try it both ways and measure the speed difference?   With a little effort, you could become and expert!

Comment: You don't need to create a new variable because you already have it. `int[] numeric = new int[operator.length + 1];`. This also ensures correct behavior even if `numberOfOperators` returns a different value the second time that you call it.

Answer (score 2):

No, it will not 'cache' or something. How could the compiler even know, if on the next call of `numberOfOperators()` there will be the same or a different result?

Comment: Quite often, it does. Just write a microbenchmark and you'll see that most of your code doesn't get executed as often as you expected (unless you really know what you're doing).

Answer (score 2):

The JIT can inline and optimize away a method call, but only if it is relatively trivial e.g. a field lookup.

Before you try to optimise your code, you should run it through a CPU and/or memory profiler and when you have measured your performance then you can decide how to optimise your code.  Anything else will be just guessing what can make a difference.

In short, make the code clear and simple to understand and worry about performance when you know you have a problem because you measured it.